# Java IO Pattern recognition

Tags: java, regex

```
BIG CONE SPRUCE,SOUTHERN CALIFORNIA, U.S.A., 1458-1966, 509 VALUES              
    120.00     64.00     56.00     88.00    109.00    100.00     18.00     58.00
     97.00     82.00     57.00    116.00    114.00    102.00     78.00    105.00
     95.00     76.00     89.00    147.00    114.00     92.00     96.00     95.00
```

I want to recongnize the data part, and I use the code as follows

```
 Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("C:\\STUDY\\MASTERARBEIT\\DATA\\MHSETS\\HURST\\BIGCONE.1"));
     s.findInLine("(\\s+\\d+\\.\\d{2})+$");
     MatchResult result = s.match();
     for (int i=1; i<=result.groupCount(); i++)
         System.out.println(result.group(i));
     s.close();
```

But the recognition failed, so, please help me point out which part is wrong. I've tried a lot 
time to modify, but still not work. Thank you so much!

Comment: you need to use find function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `matcher.find()` instead of `match()`. Match method test if the whole string match the specified regexp. find return true if a part of the string match the regexp.

Comment: No, that's not the problem.  Scanner's `match()` method returns whatever was matched by the most recent call to `findInLine()` or `findWithinHorizon()`.  You're thinking of the `matches()` method.

Answer (score 2):

I personally prefer using `Pattern` and `Matcher`, like this:

```
try {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("C:\\STUDY\\MASTERARBEIT\\DATA\\MHSETS\\HURST\\BIGCONE.1"));
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\s+\\d+\\.\\d{2})+$");
        String data;
        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            data = s.nextLine();
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);
            if (matcher.find()) {
                System.out.println(matcher.group(0)); // Or whatever you want
            }
        }
        s.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know you always have 8 columns of data, then build your regex this way:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0;i<8;++i) {
        sb.append("\\s+(\\d+\\.\\d+)");
    }
    s.findInLine(sb.toString());
```

Also, I got this to work only by removing the first line of your input (`BIG CONE SPRUCE,...`).

Answer (score 0):

I kinda managed to make it work using Scanner.findWithinHorizon but the code is quite sloppy and sometime I get an IllegalStateException because the matcher keeps going...

But I got it working using `Pattern` and `Matcher` instead! basically you jast grab each line of your input and you use the result of `Pattern.matcher()` as follow:

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("BIGCONE.1"));
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+\\.\\d{2})+");
    while (s.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = s.nextLine();
        Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
        System.out.print("line:");
        while(m.find()) {
            System.out.print(" "+m.group());
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    s.close();
```

It gives me this output:

```
line:
line: 120.00 64.00 56.00 88.00 109.00 100.00 18.00 58.00
line: 97.00 82.00 57.00 116.00 114.00 102.00 78.00 105.00
line: 95.00 76.00 89.00 147.00 114.00 92.00 96.00 95.00
```

Hope it helps :)

**Edit:** AliLofti gave the same answer a bit before me, give him credit :)

Comment: Hi, appreciated for your detail advice. Right now everything works. But your detail explanation helps me a lot!!! I understand the difference much better.